# Initialized a Two Dimensional Array using Scanner. When trying to display two dimensional array, array values are all nulled

Tags: java, arrays

I was always interested in learning an object-oriented programming language and have just got into Java. Right now I am stuck on two-dimensional arrays. I have a written a program where the user sets the values of all the elements of the array. I come across no errors, but when I display it all the values are nullified.

Here's the Code:

```
    public class TwoDimensionalArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        displayTwoDimensionalArray(firstTwoDimensionalArray);

        int secondTwoDimensionalArray[][] = new int[4][3];

        initTwoDimensionalArray(secondTwoDimensionalArray);
        displayTwoDimensionalArray(secondTwoDimensionalArray);



    }
    public static void displayTwoDimensionalArray(int x[][]) {
        for(int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < x[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(x[row][col] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void initTwoDimensionalArray(int x[][]) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int valElement;
        int row;
        int col;

        for(row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
            for(col = 0; col < x[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print("Enter the value of row " + row + " and column " + col + ".\t");
                valElement = scan.nextInt();

                valElement = x[row][col];
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Two Dimensional Array Initialized");
        System.out.println();
    }         
}
```

Here's what the console outputs:

```
 run:

Enter the value of row 0 and column 0.  7
Enter the value of row 0 and column 1.  5
Enter the value of row 0 and column 2.  4

Enter the value of row 1 and column 0.  6
Enter the value of row 1 and column 1.  9
Enter the value of row 1 and column 2.  7

Enter the value of row 2 and column 0.  4
Enter the value of row 2 and column 1.  4
Enter the value of row 2 and column 2.  3

Enter the value of row 3 and column 0.  5
Enter the value of row 3 and column 1.  5
Enter the value of row 3 and column 2.  6

Two Dimensional Array Initialized

0   0   0   
0   0   0   
0   0   0   
0   0   0   

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)
```

What did I do wrong?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Where have you declared firstTwoDimensionalArray variable?

Comment: `valElement = x[row][col];` should be `x[row][col] = valElement;`

Answer (score 0):

The manner in which you assign the inputed value to the array element needs to be reversed. The variable to which the value needs to be assigned should be on the left hand side. The line after `valElement = scan.nextInt();` needs to be changed from -

```
valElement = x[row][col];
```

to

```
x[row][col] = valElement
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know the the order you assigned it had an impact on the code. Thanks for your help!